# Flink cep key by will not decrease in usage status

Tags: apache-flink, complex-event-processing

Using FLINK CEP, the key by operator is used before the flow, and the rocksDB is used for the state backend. It is found that the state keeps rising and does not decrease, even if no new data is entered, it will not decrease until the timeout period of with in.

使用FLINK CEP，在流之前使用key by算子，状态后端使用rocksDB，发现状态一直上涨，不会下降，即使没有新数据进去，到了with in的超时时间，也不会下降。

I want the status to be cleared after a period of time exceeding within

我希望状态在超过with in的时间后进行清除

Comment: Please translate this entirely into English

Comment: The Chinese segments are simply restating what's been written in English.

Comment: Please clarify a couple of points: (1) how are you measuring the state, and (2) is the state decreasing after the timeout period expires?